# Android: Clear all backstack activities and then finish current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have various activities in my app and the flow is very complex.
What I want to do is, as soon as usb device is attached, I want to clear and finish the back stack activities, then finish the current activity and the System.exit(0) to close the app.

I have already implemented usb device listener. I want to know how do I clear and finish back stack activities(if there are any, it is not going to have any backstack activities everytime) and then finish the current one.

Also, If my activity A is on Top and it has 2 activities (B,C) in back stack. Now if activity A is running in the background and usb connected, only Activity A will listen to it right? (I have usb receiver implemented in every activity.)

How do I achieve this without my app crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is `finishAffinity()` method that will finish the current activity and all parent activities, but it works only in **Android 4.1 or higher**

**[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())**

> `finishAffinity()` will Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity

If you want for **all API levels**
in one of your activities

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will clear all the stack
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then in YourActivity onCreate() method add this to finish the Activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
   finish();
   return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
}
```

Comment: @dhun yes, Check once

Comment: Do I need to add finish() as well after calling finishAffinity() to finish the current activity?

Comment: Also, If my activity A is on Top and it has 2 activities (B,C) in back stack. Now if activity A is running in the background and usb connected, only Activity A will listen to it right? (I have usb receiver implemented in every activity.)

Comment: You shouldnt add Listeners to activities randomly. Use BroadcastReceivers for to receive events

Comment: Its like, each activity can be on top at some point, and I have to kill my application as soon as it detects usb device

Comment: finishAffinity()  will just put the application in background. It won't close the application

Answer (score -1):

In an app I made, I have put:

```
if(Globals.isExit){
  finish();
}
```

In every onResume() method in every activity.

Globals is a class that is declared as an  in the manifest.xml.
The Global class has a boolean called exit.

In all activities option menu, include an exit option thats sets Globals.exit to true, and calls finish()

Then any activities left unfinished are all finished.

Not sure if you would need to use an intent to clear the backstack or if finishing clears it for you. Sorry if im wrong on that bit.

Sorry for any bad typing, I'm on a phone.

Comment: You could also open every activity witf startForResult, and in everry activity have finish() in the on resultReturned() method